# Why my arima model is not stationary?

Tags: r, arima, stationarity

I want to fit arima model to my [data](https://github.com/aleshins/Stack.git).
To do so I run the following code:

```
library('forecast')
library('tseries')

mydata = read.csv('TDOM.csv');
mydata = ts(mydata);
fit<-auto.arima(mydata, seasonal=FALSE)
```

The resulting fit is:

```
Series: mydata 
ARIMA(1,0,1) with non-zero mean 

Coefficients:
         ar1      ma1       mean
      0.4415  -0.2199  1028.1200
s.e.  0.0257   0.0279     6.4254

sigma^2 estimated as 423253:  log likelihood=-157926.7
AIC=315861.3   AICc=315861.3   BIC=315892.9
```

Now I want to simulate this model:

```
> arima.sim(fit,10)
Error in arima.sim(fit, 10) : 'ar' part of model is not stationary
```

But if I check for stationarity it is stationary as I understand:

```
> adf.test(mydata, alternative = "stationary")

    Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test

data:  mydata
Dickey-Fuller = -26.476, Lag order = 27, p-value = 0.01
alternative hypothesis: stationary
```

**Could You explain me, where is my mistake? And what should I do to correct it?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`arima.sim()` expects parameters as follows:

> model: A list with component ‘ar’ and/or ‘ma’ giving the AR and MA
>             coefficients respectively.

Your object `fit` is not such a list. It's an object of class ARIMA, which is a list of 18 components, none of which are named "ar" or "ma".

You can, however, extract the coefficients from your `fit` and put them into the kind of `list` that `arima.sim()` expects. Note that you should also supply the estimated error standard deviation into an `sd` parameter (which will be passed through to `rnorm()`).

```
arima.sim(list(ar=fit$coef["ar1"],ma=fit$coef["ma1"]),sd=fit$sigma,10)
```

A reproducible example, e.g., random data with a set seed, would allow testing that this works correctly.